# numpy binned mean, conserving extra axes

Tags: arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, binning

It seems I am stuck on the following problem with `numpy`.

I have an array `X` with shape: `X.shape = (nexp, ntime, ndim, npart)`
I need to compute binned statistics on this array along `npart` dimension, according to the values in `binvals` (and some `bins`), but keeping all the other dimensions there, because I have to use the binned statistic to remove some bias in the original array `X`. Binning values have shape `binvals.shape = (nexp, ntime, npart)`.

A complete, minimal example, to explain what I am trying to do. Note that, in reality, I am working on large arrays and with several hunderds of bins (so this implementation takes forever):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(12345)

X = np.random.randn(24).reshape(1,2,3,4)
binvals = np.random.randn(8).reshape(1,2,4)
bins = [-np.inf, 0, np.inf]
nexp, ntime, ndim, npart = X.shape

cleanX = np.zeros_like(X)
for ne in range(nexp):
    for nt in range(ntime):
        indices = np.digitize(binvals[ne, nt, :], bins)
        for nd in range(ndim):
            for nb in range(1, len(bins)):
                inds = indices==nb
                cleanX[ne, nt, nd, inds] = X[ne, nt, nd, inds] - \
                     np.mean(X[ne, nt, nd, inds], axis = -1)
```

Looking at the results of this may make it clearer?

```
In [8]: X
Out[8]: 
array([[[[-0.20470766,  0.47894334, -0.51943872, -0.5557303 ],
         [ 1.96578057,  1.39340583,  0.09290788,  0.28174615],
         [ 0.76902257,  1.24643474,  1.00718936, -1.29622111]],

        [[ 0.27499163,  0.22891288,  1.35291684,  0.88642934],
         [-2.00163731, -0.37184254,  1.66902531, -0.43856974],
         [-0.53974145,  0.47698501,  3.24894392, -1.02122752]]]])

In [10]: cleanX
Out[10]: 
array([[[[ 0.        ,  0.67768523, -0.32069682, -0.35698841],
         [ 0.        ,  0.80405255, -0.49644541, -0.30760713],
         [ 0.        ,  0.92730041,  0.68805503, -1.61535544]],

        [[ 0.02303938, -0.02303938,  0.23324375, -0.23324375],
         [-0.81489739,  0.81489739,  1.05379752, -1.05379752],
         [-0.50836323,  0.50836323,  2.13508572, -2.13508572]]]])


In [12]: binvals
Out[12]: 
array([[[ -5.77087303e-01,   1.24121276e-01,   3.02613562e-01,
           5.23772068e-01],
        [  9.40277775e-04,   1.34380979e+00,  -7.13543985e-01,
          -8.31153539e-01]]])
```

Is there a vectorized solution? I thought of using `scipy.stats.binned_statistic`, but I seem to be unable to understand how to use it for this aim. Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide some dummy input?

Comment: What do you mean? anything can do: `X=np.random.randn(120).reshape(3,4,2,5)`, `binvals=np.random.randn(24).reshape(3,4,2)` and `bins=np.linspace(binvals.min(), binvals.max(), 10)`

Comment: I am getting `IndexError: boolean index did not match..` with the sample data on the posted code.

Comment: Indeed, that's because I put the wrong shape of binvals. It should be: `X=np.random.randn(120).reshape(3,4,2,5)`, `binvals=np.random.randn(60).reshape(3,4,5)` and `bins=np.linspace(binvals.min(), binvals.max(), 10)` as in the question.

Comment: It is much easier to tackle these problems if you identify some inputs and expected outputs. https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I tried to make the question clearer according to your suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it, mainly based on the answer by @jdehesa.

```
clean2 = np.zeros_like(X)
d = np.digitize(binvals, bins)
for i in range(1, len(bins)):
    m = d == i
    minds = np.where(m)
    sl = [*minds[:2], slice(None), minds[2]]
    msum = m.sum(axis=-1)
    clean2[sl] = (X - \
                  (np.sum(X * m[...,np.newaxis,:], axis=-1) / 
                  msum[..., np.newaxis])[..., np.newaxis])[sl]
```

Which gives the same results as my original code.
On the small arrays I have in the example here, this solution is approximately three times as fast as the original code. I expect it to be way faster on larger arrays.

*Update:*

Indeed it's faster on larger arrays (didn't do any formal test), but despite this, it just reaches the level of acceptable in terms of performance... any further suggestion on extra vectoriztaions would be very welcome.

Comment: I've updated my answer too. My code does not give the same results, but... when I run it produces values close to zero (which I guess is the point), where as your original code produces values up to +/- 6 (which is weird because `X` values are in `[0, 1]`)... I don't know what's the difference though! Just in case it's useful to you...

Comment: @jdehesa X values are from the standard normal distribution, so they are not limited to [0,1]. I checked my code and it does what I need, even if maybe not as fast as I wished for. In any case, thanks a lot for the suggestion, it was very useful at least to improve significantly the performance!

Answer (score 2):

```
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(100)

nexp = 3
ntime = 4
ndim = 5
npart = 100
nbins = 4

binvals = np.random.rand(nexp, ntime, npart)
X = np.random.rand(nexp, ntime, ndim, npart)
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, nbins + 1)

d = np.digitize(binvals, bins)[:, :, np.newaxis, :]
r = np.arange(1, len(bins)).reshape((-1, 1, 1, 1, 1))
m = d[np.newaxis, ...] == r
counts = np.sum(m, axis=-1, keepdims=True).clip(min=1)
means = np.sum(X[np.newaxis, ...] * m, axis=-1, keepdims=True) / counts
cleanX = X - np.choose(d - 1, means)
```

Comment: Well, I have to think more about it, but it does not really seem to me to be the same thing I was looking for.

Comment: @user6760680 I've added an alternative solution with no loops (should be faster), at the expense of more memory.

Comment: It took me a while to understand what did not convince me, but the point is that you are binning a, while I have to compute the statistics on a, but binning a different array.

Comment: @user6760680 Okay right I see what you mean, I misunderstood the problem, I'll fix it.

Comment: Btw the answer uses [`np.choose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.choose.html) at the end, which apparently is limited to 32 different choices (so you would only be able to use up to 32 bins)... you would need a different path for that last step if you need more...